# How to get a list of duplicate values from 2 columns in csv with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am new to pandas and I am trying to get a list of duplicate values from 2 columns of a CSV file, my data frame looks like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
PID1    PID2
1       2
2       3
3       3
4       4
5       6
6       7
7       8
7       9
7       9
```

I've tried using this :

```
df.drop_duplicates('PID1', 'PID2', inplace=True)
print(df)
```

But I think it does not work with 2 columns.

Expected output would be either adding a new column to my CSV file with a title 'Duplicates' and add all duplicates from two columns or a simple list which would hold all duplicate values.

```
Duplicates
2
3
4
6
7
```

Comment: Do you want `df['PID2'].drop_duplicates()` ?

Comment: Hi @jezrael, I've updated my question. I want to check if value in PID1 exists in PID2. So since 1 only exists in PID1 it is not a duplicate. Since 4 exists both in PID1 and PID2 it is a duplicate. Since 9 only exists twice in PID2 it is not a duplicate.

Comment: pass multiple columns as a sequence i.e. list or tuple `df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['PID1', 'PID2'], inplace=True)`

Comment: yop, answer was edited. now it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filtering and then use [`Series.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html):

```
s = df.loc[df['PID1'].isin(df['PID2']), 'PID1'].drop_duplicates()
print (s)
1    2
2    3
3    4
5    6
6    7
Name: PID1, dtype: int64
```